# Problema com uma função em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou tentando fazer uma função de calcular IMC, mas quando tento executar dá um error:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: imcDoPrimo is not defined
>       at"

```
var mostrar = function(frases) {
    document.write(frases);
}
var pularLinhar = function(){
    document.write('<br>');
}


//var peso = 70;
//var altura = 1.75;
//var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
//('Meu IMC é: ' + imc.toFixed(2));
// pularLinhar();

var calcularIMC = function(altura, peso){
    var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
    return imc;
}

var pesoDoPrimo = 70;
var AlturaDoPrimo = 1.75;
calcularIMC(AlturaDoPrimo, pesoDoPrimo);

mostrar("O imc do primo é: " + imcDoPrimo);
mostrar("Ele ainda está " + (imcDoPrimo - 18.5) 
        + "pontos acima do limite da magreza.");
```

Comment: Rapaz, bastava colocar no Google Tradutor `imcDoPrimo is not defined at` que retornaria `imcDoPrimo não está definido em`, ou seja, variável não definida!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere essa linha

```
var pesoDoPrimo = 70;
var AlturaDoPrimo = 1.75;
calcularIMC(AlturaDoPrimo, pesoDoPrimo);
```

para

```
var pesoDoPrimo = 70;
var AlturaDoPrimo = 1.75;
var imcDoPrimo = calcularIMC(AlturaDoPrimo, pesoDoPrimo);
```

Pois você não está declarando a variavel  **imcDoPrimo**